# Multi ViewPager change padding

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-sliding

I'm implementing ViewPager on Android TV to show 3 items like this (background green/purple are debug background to depict whole ViewPager's page): 
[image]

I archieved that using:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
...
        android:paddingLeft="300px"
        android:paddingRight="300px"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
... 
/>
```

When **loosing focus** on ViewPager I wanted **central item** to scale down and **pages to come closer together**. To achieve that plugged animation:

```
                ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(300, 400);
                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator){
                        Integer paddingHorizontal = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        vpScreenshots.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, 0, paddingHorizontal, 0);
                    }
                });
                animator.setDuration(300);
                animator.start();
```

The animation works perfect for 1st element:
[image]

However when moving to next pages (both left and right) the padding animation starts to behave strange. When **moving** e.g. **to right** padding animation **doesn't take action on left item** but rather central and right ones. The effects goes deeper the more I move to right. The results are:
[image]
[image]

So **switching pages** in ViewPager **spoils items alignment** when padding animation occurs.
Why does it happen? How ti fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. The only way which seems to work is to manipulate left and right items' "x" parameter.

Here is the code for focus listener:

```
              if (hasFocus) {
                Map<Integer, View> neighbors = vpScreenshots.findNeighbors();
                View leftNeighbor = neighbors.get(0);
                View rightNeighbor = neighbors.get(1);
                if (!firstFocus) {
                    leftNeighbor.animate().xBy(-100).setDuration(FOCUS_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                    rightNeighbor.animate().xBy(100).setDuration(FOCUS_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                }
                firstFocus = false;
            } else {
                Map<Integer, View> neighbors = vpScreenshots.findNeighbors();
                View leftNeighbor = neighbors.get(0);
                View rightNeighbor = neighbors.get(1);

                leftNeighbor.animate().xBy(100).setDuration(FOCUS_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
                rightNeighbor.animate().xBy(-100).setDuration(FOCUS_ANIMATION_DURATION).start();
            }
```

Looking for neighbor items is attached to MyViewPager class:

```
    public Map<Integer, View> findNeighbors() {
    neighbors = new HashMap<>();
    int currentPosition = getCurrentItem();
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View childView = getChildAt(i);

        int childPosition = (int) childView.getTag();
        if ((currentPosition - childPosition) == 1) {
            neighbors.put(0, childView);
        }

        if ((currentPosition - childPosition) == -1) {
            neighbors.put(1, childView);
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, could you please paste the entire code?